# Single visual studio .sln for multiple CmakeLists.txt projects?

Tags: cmake

Let's say I have a folder structure like:

```
CMakeLists.txt
/ProjThatShouldProduceLib/CMakeLists.txt
/ProjThatUsesLibShouldProduceExe/CMakeLists.txt
/AnotherProjThatUsesLibShouldProduceExe/CMakeLists.txt
```

How do I get the root `CMakeLists.txt` to produce a visual studio `.sln` that contains all the other directories as projects?

Comment: The command is `add_subdirectory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(proj)

add_subdirectory(ProjThatShouldProduceLib)
add_subdirectory(ProjThatUsesLibShouldProduceExe)
add_subdirectory(AnotherProjThatUsesLibShouldProduceExe)
```